# Node JS to PHP, cannot get it working

Tags: php, node.js

I am trying to replicate some Node JS into PHP but cannot seem to get it working! The node is below;

```
function initLogin(callback) {
    debug('Getting login');
    request.get({
            url: psnURL.SignIN
            , headers : {
                'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 4.3; '+options.npLanguage+'; C6502 Build/10.4.1.B.0.101) AppleWebKit/534.30 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/534.30 PlayStation App/1.60.5/'+options.npLanguage+'/'+options.npLanguage
            }
        }
        , function (error, response, body) {
            (typeof callback === "function" ? getLogin(callback, psnVars.SENBaseURL + response.req.path) : getLogin(undefined, psnVars.SENBaseURL + response.req.path));
    })
}
/*
* @desc     Login into PSN/SEN and creates a session with an auth code
* @param    Function callback - Calls this function once the login is complete
*/
function getLogin(callback, url) {
    request.post(psnURL.SignINPOST
        ,{
            headers: {
                'Origin':'https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com'
                ,'Referer': url
            }
            ,form:{
                'params'        : 'service_entity=psn'
                ,'j_username'   : options.email
                ,'j_password'   : options.password
            }
        }, function (error, response, body) {
            request.get(response.headers.location, function (error, response, body) {
                if (!error) {
                    var urlString = unescape(response.req.path);
                    psnVars.authCode = urlString.substr(urlString.indexOf("authCode=") + 9, 6);
                    debug('authCode obtained: ' + psnVars.authCode);
                    getAccessToken(psnVars.authCode, callback);
                }
                else {
                    debug('ERROR: ' + error)
                }
            })
        }
    )
}
```

And my PHP which I cannot get working;

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(

    CURLOPT_URL => $PSNSignIn,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => realpath('/tmp/cookieJar.txt'),
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,

));
$res = curl_exec($c);

$path = explode($SENBaseURL, curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
$referer = $SENBaseURL . $path[1];

var_dump(file_get_contents('tmp/cookieJar.txt'), $res);

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(

    CURLOPT_URL => $SignINPOST,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $referer,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => array(
        'Origin: https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ),
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(

        'params' => 'service_entity=psn',
        'j_username' => $username,
        'j_password' => $password,
    ),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'tmp/cookieJar',
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
));

$res = curl_exec($c);

var_dump($res, curl_getinfo($c));
```

It is supposed to login into Sony’s servers and retrieve a OAuth code, the Node.js is working so it is possible but I cannot seem to get it working in PHP.

Any help would be much appreciated.

The CURL is working but I get an `?authentication_error=true` when it should return a code which I can utilize.

Comment: is your content type correct? 
'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

Comment: Make sure you have turned on notices/warnings, so your vars we can't see (e.g. `$userAgent`) raise the alarm if they are accidentally not in scope.

Comment: Yes they are all in scope, as a side note the full node.js api can be found here https://github.com/jhewt/gumer-psn and even a PHP implementation of it can be found here, https://github.com/ilendemli/gumer-psn-php

Comment: I am just trying to get an understanding of it within my local environment

Comment: You have an error with your COOKIEJAR file. You are using an absolute path initially and missing the leading forward-slash in the latter usage.

Comment: I'll implement and see what happens, thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting `Authentication Error` because, in the line

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => 'tmp/cookieJar`
```

You are using the wrong value for the `cookieJar` for `CURL`. You need to add `.txt` and correct the path to an absolute path like you've used earlier in your code. That's why `CURL` is throwing  you an `Authentication Error`

Correcting that with the following should solve your problems.

```
CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => '/tmp/cookieJar.txt`
```

**Also** change the following line

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('tmp/cookieJar.txt'), $res);
```

**Like this:**

```
var_dump(file_get_contents('/tmp/cookieJar.txt'), $res);
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comments you used relative paths in two occasions and in the last usage you omitted the `.txt`:

```
$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(

    CURLOPT_URL => $PSNSignIn,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => true,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR => realpath('/tmp/cookieJar.txt'),
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,

));
$res = curl_exec($c);

$path = explode($SENBaseURL, curl_getinfo($c, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL));
$referer = $SENBaseURL . $path[1];

var_dump(file_get_contents('/tmp/cookieJar.txt'), $res);

$c = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($c, array(

    CURLOPT_URL => $SignINPOST,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => $userAgent,
    CURLOPT_REFERER => $referer,
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
    CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
    CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => 2,
    CURLOPT_HEADER => array(
        'Origin: https://auth.api.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com',
        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    ),
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(

        'params' => 'service_entity=psn',
        'j_username' => $username,
        'j_password' => $password,
    ),
    CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE => '/tmp/cookieJar.txt',
    CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => 1,
));

$res = curl_exec($c);

var_dump($res, curl_getinfo($c));
```